# Getting all the objects that have no records in other tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to sql and I'm trying to get all the projects that have no records in some other tables. For example; There are many projects and projects have many sources but there some projects who do not have any sources at all. I want to retrieve only the projects who do not have any records in the other table... This is the code that i tried but it still gives me some projects that do have sources. Can anyone help me with this?Thanks!

```
SELECT        
                    p_Project.Project_ID as Id
                  , p_Project.ProjectNum
                  , p_Project.ProjectName
                  , p_Project.Client_ID 
                  , p_Project.Industry
                  , p_Project.ProjectStatus
                  , p_Project.EffectiveDate
                  , p_Project.ProjectOrigination
                  , p_Project.ProjDateClosed
                  , p_Project.PrimaryMaterial
                  , p_Project.PrimaryService
                  , p_Project.PrimarySource
                  , p_Project.ProjectCategory
                  , p_Client.Client_ID as Id
                  , p_Client.ClientName
            FROM  p_Project
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     p_Client ON p_Project.Client_ID = p_Client.Client_ID 
            WHERE p_Project.Project_ID IN (  SELECT p_Project.Project_ID
                                 FROM  p_Project
                                 LEFT OUTER JOIN p_Client ON p_Project.Client_ID = p_Client.Client_ID WHERE p_Project.Project_ID IN (SELECT p_Project.Project_ID as Id FROM p_Project   WHERE  p_Project.ProjectStatus  ='active') AND p_Project.Project_ID IN (SELECT p_Project.Project_ID as Id FROM p_Project LEFT OUTER JOIN p_Project_Pricing ON p_Project.Project_ID = p_Project_Pricing.Project_ID  WHERE (  p_Project_Pricing.SourceCode  IS NULL OR  p_Project_Pricing.SourceCode  LIKE N'') AND ( p_Project.PrimarySource  IS NULL OR p_Project.PrimarySource  LIKE N''))
                                GROUP BY p_Project.Project_ID, p_Client.ClientName, p_Project.ProjectName, p_Project.ProjectNum
                                ORDER BY p_Client.ClientName, p_Project.ProjectName, p_Project.ProjectNum
                                OFFSET (0) ROWS FETCH NEXT (25) ROWS ONLY )
```

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below.

```
select proj.* from [yourprojtable] proj
left join [yoursourcetable] src
on proj.projid = src.projid
where src.projid is null
```

In your query try changing the where condition as 'where P_Client.Client_id is null'.

Comment: @BYG You can also accept this as an answer if you find this useful.